# Disable AutoCorrect with Subliminal

Tags: ios, testing, autocorrect, subliminal

I'm running into issues in my subliminal tests where text is auto-corrected due to the device defaults.

Is there a way for me to disable auto-correct on the entire devices using Subliminal? 
Can I navigate to the device settings somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Subliminal can't navigate to the device settings, but your tests can override the default text field autocorrection type with a bit of [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/):

```
// In the test that exercises the text fields,
// or a base test class of multiple tests that exercise text fields
#import <objc/runtime.h>

- (void)setUpTest {
    // `dispatch_once` in case this is a base test class,
    // where this method would be called multiple times
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        struct objc_method_description autocorrectionTypeMethodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(UITextInputTraits), @selector(autocorrectionType), NO, YES);
        // (Re)implement `-[UITextField autocorrectionType]` to return `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNO`.
        IMP noAutocorrectionTypeIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(^(UITextField *_self){ return UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; });
        class_replaceMethod([UITextField class], @selector(autocorrectionType), noAutocorrectionTypeIMP, autocorrectionTypeMethodDescription.types);
    });
}
```